# inject select2 in typeScript

Tags: jquery-select2, typescript1.4

I have problem injecting the select2 library in my TypeScript/Angular project. I don't know what else to do to make it working, I searched for some working example of but without success.

- jQuery gets loaded
- select2.js gets loaded
- definition file select2.d.ts is there (I also have matching version)

Module is injected like that:

```
public init() {
        var myApp = angular.module('app', [
            'ui.router',
            'ngCookies',
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'select2'
        ]); 
...
```

I get an error:

```
Module 'select2' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

What am I doing wrong there? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this by initializing select2 in jQuery style direct in my controller...

```
$('select').select2();
```

It is probably not very nice solution but it works. If anyone got better solution feel free to post it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject Select2 into your application like an Angular module. This is throwing an error because Select2 is **not an angular module**, it's a jQuery component.

Angular UI provides [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) which is an Angular native version of Select2.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately there is no definition file for ui-select available. With my lack of typeScript skills I will not be able to create one and use it with the typeScript